# How to match the local transforms to another object without rotating the model

Tags: modeling, transforms, transform-orientation

I'm trying to match one objects orientation to another without changing the model rotation.
I was able to come close to what I wanted by creating a custom orientation, but I would need to apply that custom orientation to the locals of the current object to get what I want.

**EXAMPLE:**

Starting with two objects with different local transforms:

[image: unaligned]

I want a way to make the local rotation of the top object to match the local rotation of the bottom object without moving the mesh itself:

[image: aligned]

I can get close to what I want by creating a Custom Orientation out of the bottom object and using that with my tool, but I would like to be able to apply this to my local rotations instead of relying on using the custom orientation:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I was close but was just missing the 4th step below:

1. Enable Transform > Affect Only > Origins
2. Select the object whose orientation you want to change, SHIFT + CLICK the object you want to match
3. Object > Transform > Align to Transform Orientation
4. Change from Global to Local

[image: matching orienation to another object]

Shoutout to moonboots for prompting me to check again which was when I noticed this setting.

Answer (score 0):

Select the bottom cube. In the *Transform Orientations* panel, switch from *Global* to *Local*. Activate the *Transform Affect Only > Origins* option, select the top object, shift select the bottom object to make it the active object, go into *Object > Transform > Align to Transform Orientation*:

[image]

Comment: That's what I would have assumed too but I tried that earlier and it just set the orientation of both objects to match the global/scene defaults

EDIT: I figured it out: after doing this I need to change the action settings so it applies to local rather than global, which is the default. Thanks for prompting me to check again because that felt correct to me, I was just missing one setting

Comment: OK I've edited  ;)